# Table to json error - DbContext has been disposed

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

for some reason my DBContext is just not working, i have a very simple action on my controller and I'm getting this error `The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.`

my simple code is the following,(the .toList() is only for debug to confrim data is being read and i have a list of 102 elements.)

```
public ActionResult gettimeoffsets()
    {
        using (Dal.DbContext dc = new Dal.DbContext())
        {
            var times = dc.timeZones;
            var timelist = times.ToList();
            return Json(times, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

this is my timezone model

```
 [Table("timeZones")]
public class timeZone
{
    [Key]
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String BaseUtcOffset { get; set; }
    public String DisplayName { get; set; }
    public Double tzOffset { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using `times` in the JSON response which will is probably a `DbSet` or similar `IQueryable` object. You need to use `timelist` in the JSON response which has executed the database query.

Comment: i did not not that Dbset could not be returned, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably have lazy-loading and proxy-generation enabled and your `TimeZone` object have navigation properties in them. When the serializer tries to load the dependencies, the context is already disposed, that's why you get the exception.

Try disabling lazy-loading and proxy-generation in your context.

```
dc.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled=false;
dc.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled=false;
```

EDIT:
Try returning the `times` instead of `timeZones`. `times` is an `IQueryable`, which is also only evaluated when the serializer tries to return it, but by that time your context, through which the evaluation could happen, is already disposed.

Comment: i don't think that's the case, i have edited the post to add my model

Comment: I think we have a similar problem in this case too. I missed the fact the you were returning an IQueryable, sorry about that. See the edit for details.